# List of auto-banned IPs in IIS?

Tags: iis, ftp, ip

I have configured the "FTP Logon Attempt Restrictions" feature in IIS, but nowhere can I find where restricted IPs are listed.

There must be a list somewhere that IIS will uses at logon.

So my question is, is it possible to view this list somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I would say the list of IP addresses is only hold in memory. The server only has so "remember" some recent requests and can discard them after the specified time period has expired. It seems there is no documented way to get to this list.

If you review your normal FTP logs you will see failed logins `status 530`, you can use LogParser or other tools to group and filter your logs to see the IP addresses in question.